# How to use the Freehand Curve drawing add-on?

Tags: add-on

Enabled/Installed the add-on, can not get it to work though...

There's the Options tab in the T-Tools panel, but there is no Draw Curve button in the Create tab.... Shift+LMB does not work as well...

Any idea why this might be?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Took me some tries to figure it out myself:

1. Add a Bezier curve to your scene
2. Tab into Edit Mode (with said curve selected)
3. Shift+LMB draw your freehand curve
4. Delete the Bezier curve from step 1

Comment: Oh, its RMB for me. Cheers :D

Comment: Though, for some reason, I also do not have the tolerance feature/setting, and the ability to switch btween Cursor and Surface and also pressure radius........ :((